# $[\mathbb{Q}(\beta) : \mathbb{Q}(\beta^3)] \leq 3$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory, extension-field, minimal-polynomials

when doing an exercise concerning field extensions, i've found one that stumped me. The question is that, given $\beta \in \mathbb{C}$, it is the case that the field extension $\mathbb{Q}(\beta^3) \subset \mathbb{Q}(\beta)$ is at most of degree 3, with all lower degrees occuring for some $\beta$. Now I have found examples for degree 2 ($e^\frac{2\pi\cdot i}{3}$ does the trick, its minimal polynomial is the second cyclotomic) and ofcourse 1, but I am unable to find one for degree 3. Also the inequality itsself is puzzling to me, I have a strong suspicion that one could try showing this using $\beta$'s minimal polynomial over $\mathbb{Q}$, but I have no idea where to start. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well the inequality simply comes from the fact that the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $\Bbb{Q}(\beta^3)$ must divide $X^3 -\beta^3$ so its degree is less than $3$. Now for a case where it is equal to $3$ what about $\beta = 2^{1/3}$ ? $X^3 - 2$ is irreducible over $\Bbb{Q} = \Bbb{Q}(\beta^3)$

Comment: Oh ofcourse, thanks!  Don't know why I didn't think of the first part :-) The example you've given is also quite cute

Comment: The fun question is, can it be $2$? It can clearly be $1$ - taking $\beta=\sqrt{2}$.

Comment: @Thomasandrews : OP mentions the case $n=2$